# Use background image as page structure?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working in a place that we have to use images as page structure, I would like to know how wrong it is, because in my eyes is very wrong and.. I can never make perfect the layout because of the difficulty to fix the correct content over the image.

Is there any right way to do this? Any course to teach me an easy way?

Example: http://bit.ly/1GILaQs
BG: http://bit.ly/1GILfDy

We need give support to IE8, so is more difficult.

Thanks

Comment: You're right: that is a terrible idea for numerous reasons. Can't you just ask for the different layers as separate image files from the graphics designer who made it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal should be to reduce that file size of that image because it is very large and takes a long time to load. And also to make the layout more flexible so that when you change something you don't have to open up an image editor and rearrange things.

I don't think it is possible to replicate what you have there exactly without using large images but what I would do is try and replace some elements with simpler more easily repeatable patterns. For example replacing the red background with a simpler symmetrical gradient and removing the shadows/folds from the white image. Then for the shampoo bottles you could use individual image tags and place them within your content.

Answer (score 0):

Amanda, you can have a background image that can be repeated, the red part of the layout background. Then you can have a div with the white part.I believe that's the best you can have.

I don't believe there will be a magic way that will give you the layout flexibility you're looking for. You will have to work with Photoshop and adapt the content accordingly given the nature of the layout.

Code School offers some good courses, they have one about css that can help you on that: https://www.codeschool.com/courses/css-cross-country